# When a user fills a form wrongly/misses something how do I show an error message through JS on ruby on rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a form in my app (standard fill in name, surname, email), I would like to know how to show an error message if the user misses a section/doesn't fill it correctly. My validations are that none of these sections can be blank. I am mostly unsure as to how I can connect my controller to my JS file to call the error message or if there is any better way.

My HTML:

```
    <%= form_for @contestant, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                                <input type="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="surname">Surname:</label>
                                <input type="surname" class="form-control" id="surname" placeholder="Surname">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="example@gmail.com">
                            </div>
<% end %>
```

This is the controller:

```
   class ContestantsController < ApplicationController
    def new 
        @contestant = Contestant.new 
    end 
    def create 
        @contestant = Contestant.new(contestant_params)
        if @contestant.errors.any?
            #I don't know how to connect with the JS section?
        else
            #I don't know how to connect with the JS section?
        end
    end 
    private 
    def contestant_params 
        params.require(:contestant).permit(:name, :surname, :email)
    end 
   end
```

Some help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can approach this.

1. Do some basic client side validation checks, such as checking for required fields, required format etc. This would be a js file in the assets/javascripts folder of your project. However you should also perform validation in the back end as well.
2. Another approach would be to submit the form using ajax. Simply add remote: true to the form_for line

   ```
   <%= form_for @contestant, :remote => true, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
   ```

   In the controller, you will need a respond_to block to handle the ajax request.

   ```
   respond_to do |format|
     if @contestant.save
       format.html { redirect_to @contestant, notice: 'Contestant could not be created.' }
       format.js   {}
       format.json { render json: @contestant}
     else
       format.html { render action: "new" }
       format.json { render json: @contestant.errors }
     end
   end
   ```

There is a lot of information [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html).

Answer (score 0):

In rails you can use the client_side_validation gem, which will pick the model validations and apply it to front_end validation.

Include ClientSideValidations in your Gemfile

```
gem 'client_side_validations'
```

Then run the install generator

```
rails g client_side_validations:install
```

add this to application.js

```
//= require rails.validations
```

and use form as

```
<%= form_for @user, validate: true do |f| %>
```

This will manage client side validation for you. Here is the link of the gem github page which you can review for more options [client_side_validation_rails](https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations)

Answer (score 0):

In rails you use `ActiveModel::Validators` to validate your models.

So your code should look like this:

```
class Contestant
  validates_presence_of :name, :surname, :email
end
```

Now in your controller you do the following:

```
def create 
    @contestant = Contestant.new(contestant_params)
    if @contestant.save
      redirect_to @contestant
    else
      render :new
    end
end
```

and in your view:

```
<%= form_for @contestant %>
  <% if @contestant.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <ul>
      <% @contestant.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

For such a simple validation like the `presence` of something you might not want  to use any gem or javascript code, a way would be setting the html attribute `required=true` on your required attributes.